# Recursive app dependencies django

Tags: django, python-3.x

Django's `INSTALLED_APPS` is a list in the settings file, which ultimately the devops girl/guy of the wsgi-application is responsible for.

However, when creating an app, I often use templates and templatetags of other apps, for example django-bootstrap4. Consider a simple bootstrap4-with-butter app, that only proivides this template:

`bs4wb/templates/bs4wb/base.html`

```py
{% extends "bootstrap4/bootstrap4.html" %}

{% block bootstrap4_extra_head %}
<script> confirm('with butter?!'); </script>
{% endblock bootstrap4_extra_head %}
```

It is not enough for the devops to install and add to INSTALLED_APPS 
`bs4wb`, they also need to do the same for `django-bootstrap4`, and moreover, he/she also needs to keep track of the version I used whenever I upgrade from `django-bootstrap4` to django-bootstrap5` or something. That is, I need to document an extra step which can change.

How can I specify recursive INSTALLED_APPS? Is there something like an app-union? For example (obviously ugly syntax, sorry):

```py
export('bs4wb', app_by_union(['bootstrap4', 'bs4wb']) )
```

which would insert `bootstrap4` and `bs4wb` next to each other whenever `bs4wb` is added to `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Or should I just raise an exception if `bootstrap4` was not added to installed apps, stating that it should be added.

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv?  What do you need that doing `pip freeze` once you have everything installed doesn't do? As you've described it, you'll have all of this installed on your local machine - pip freeze > requirements.txt it, and then whoever is deploying can install using `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Comment: The issue is not whether the requirements are installed in site-packages, the issue is whether they are added tot `INSTALLED_APPS` in the proper order.

Comment: Why is it that if someone down votes, they do not comment on the reasons? If you want me to keep asking mediocre questions, please continue not explaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an app developer you usually use django's [system check framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/checks/) to ensure the environment fits your requirements.

In your case you'll check whether another app is included in `INSTALLED_APPS` and add an error, if not.

It might look like that (untested):

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.checks import Error, register

@register()
def bootstrap4_check(app_configs, **kwargs):
    errors = []
    if not 'django-bootstrap4' in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
        errors.append(
            Error('django-bootstrap4 needs to be in INSTALLED_APPS')
        )
    return errors
```

If your requirements change with new versions: adjust the checks.

Comment: Where do you place this code? Is it run for every http-request?

Comment: Nope we usually put this into **app_root/checks.py** - django does not load this file automatically, so we also include it in **app_root/__init__.py**: `from . import checks`